# return one value with multiple criteria in different rows & columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help creating a formula that returns one value with multiple criteria in different rows & columns.

For example, I want to return the November Hours for the Parent, John's child, Phil.

I need to be able to match John and Phil (in two columns) to November Hours (a row) to return a value within the array of D4:G9. The correct answer would be 4, but every time I try a traditional INDEX(MATCH), I get an N/A.

I attached a picture of my sample data.

[image: My Sample Data]

Comment: You could use SUMIFS but life would be a lot easier if you filled in the blanks in column B.

Comment: How would i go about using a SUMIF is if filled them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Column B filled in as the comments suggest:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(D:G,0,MATCH("November Hours",$D$2:$G$2,0)),B:B,"John",C:C,"Phil")
```

Comment: Scott this only works i think if no blanks in column B? I.e. parent name repeats? confirmed - i dont 100% follow the reference to "as comments suggest" - just trying to learn by recreating the test data and your proposal - thanks in advance for clarification

Comment: @JohnnieL see the comment by SJR above.  Correct, it will not work unless all the cells in B are filled in with the correct parent.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!